# How can I conditionally use two different flyout menus in my UserControl in UWp

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have a UserControl that contains a button, and when the button is clicked, a flyout menu should appear. However, I would like to use different flyout menus depending on a specific condition.

I have created a dependency property in my UserControl that determines which flyout menu to display, and a converter that converts the value of the dependency property to the corresponding flyout menu.
How do I change the value of dependency property from the view

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way to do this is modify the `MenuFlyout` object in the code behind. You could change the items of the `MenuFlyout` manually based on  the specific condition.

I notice that you are creating in the converter. So want you need to do is to create the `MenuFlyoutItems` in the converter.

Here is a simple demo which I made. The button's MenuFlyout will change after another button is clicked.

**Xaml:**

```
    <StackPanel>
    <Button  x:Name="MyButton" Content="Click" >
        <Button.Flyout>
            <MenuFlyout  x:Name="TestFlyout">
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Change color"  />
            </MenuFlyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>

    <Button Content="ChangeMenuItem" Click="MyButton_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
 bool testFlag= false;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (testFlag)
        {
            GenerateItemA();
            testFlag = false;
        }
        else 
        {
            GenerateItemB();
            testFlag = true;
        }

    }

    private void GenerateItemA() 
    {

        // remove all the existing items
        TestFlyout.Items.Clear();

        TestFlyout.Items.Add(new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "Group A" });
        TestFlyout.Items.Add(new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "Group B" });
        TestFlyout.Items.Add(new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "Group c" });
    }

    private void GenerateItemB()
    {
        // remove all the existing items
        TestFlyout.Items.Clear();

        TestFlyout.Items.Add(new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "Group 123" });
        TestFlyout.Items.Add(new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "Group 234" });
        TestFlyout.Items.Add(new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "Group 435" });

    }
```